# curl to resuse https connection sessions

Tags: curl, https, libcurl

I have built curl with openssl and I am able to execute the https connection .

Now every time when curl make TLS connection it makes handshake again  .

I need to  make use of the client with  previous connection  session ID of the server and  use it in  next request . I have tried the below option but still its making the new handshake for every try

```
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, https://127.0.0.1);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, headerfile);

  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE,"PEM");


  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLCERT,"My.cert");


  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE,"PEM");

  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLKEY,"My.Key");


  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_CAINFO,".");


  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1L);

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"seesion.id") 


  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

  if(res != CURLE_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",


 }

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

I tried this do with curl but could not  ,  Can some body suggest me how to do this with cCURL ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-use the same curl handle in subsequent requests! Don't call [curl_easy_cleanup](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_cleanup.html)(curl) and [curl_easy_init](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html)() again between them.

Comment: this is working fine for single client .. now if another curl client appl (which is on the same host)wants to use same session ID to fetch resource , does that client application needs set all the set option and call curl_handle() ?

Comment: It just reuse CURL handler but not tcp connection.