# libcurl: how does connection Keep-Alive work?

Tags: c, http, libcurl

How do I keep connection alive with libcurl?

The usage that I'd like is the following. I want to connect to a server that supports `Keep-Alive` but which closes the connection after 90 seconds of inactivity. I want to do `POST` once in a while when some events (outside of this connection) occur, and I want to keep the connection alive in order to reduce latency. It might happen that no event occurs for more than 90 seconds, so I want a way to tell the server I'm not idle.

The examples page is excellent, but I don't see one involving `Keep-Alive`: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

I did find `CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL`: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL.html, but it's not clear to me how it's supposed to work. In that example, we see the code:

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");

  /* enable TCP keep-alive for this transfer */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);

  /* set keep-alive idle time to 120 seconds */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE, 120L);

  /* interval time between keep-alive probes: 60 seconds */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL, 60L);

  curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
```

The description says the following:

> Pass a long. Sets the interval, in seconds, that the operating system will wait between sending keepalive probes. Not all operating systems support this option. (Added in 7.25.0)

Two questions:

A) Operationally, how do I use this? From the description, it looks like as long as I keep `curl` in scope, the connection will remain open. Is this correct? And then should I just keep doing

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postthis);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

whenever I want to `POST` more data and it will be sent in the same connection, or is there more to it?

B) What are these keepalive probes and where can I read more about them? Is this something that the OS does behind my back? Should I think of this as: from the point of view of my application, the connection is magically alive and I shouldn't worry about it?

---

Yes, I meant HTTP `Keep-Alive`, sorry for the ambiguity.

Since yesterday, I found that Daniel Stenberg himself has answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14148171/12874900

This answers part A) of my question. But it doesn't answer question B). I would also need to know: if the connection does die for whatever reason, how am I meant to detect it? Or does libcurl take care of the reconnect?

Someone feel free to edit this into my original post.

Comment: It should happen by default, as it is enabled by default from HTTP 1.1 on.

Comment: @cyalin are you talking about TCP connection keepalive or HTTP keepalive?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Read the title and the question. The question oesn't make any sense when read as being about TCP keepalive. It mentions 'connection keepalive', which is practically the name of the HTTP header concerned, and how long the server keeps the connection open, which is what HTTP keepalive does.

Comment: @user207421 the only fact that suggests HTTP keep alive to me is the fact it mentions POST requests. Let's say that I'll delete the answer right away and undelete if needed, sounds like a better idea. You're most probably right and it's my bad.

Comment: TCP keep-alive has nothing to do with HTTP keep-alive. Unless I suppose you have a server that allows holding connections open for hours.

Comment: And another comment about TCP keepalive. The name is deceptive. With it turned off the connection would stay alive by default. It's real purpose is to KILL OFF TCP connections that can no longer communicate.

Answer (score 9):

## HTTP persistent connections

As said many times: libcurl does persistent HTTP connections by default. You just have to reuse the curl handles for that to work and you have to actively ask for *not* doing them persistent if you don't want them. It doesn't matter what HTTP method you use. GET, POST, HEAD etc all maintain the connection - unless something out of the ordinary happens.

Modern libcurl versions will however only reuse connections up [CURLOPT_MAXAGE_CONN](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MAXAGE_CONN.html) seconds (118 by default) - since the chance of successful reuse diminishes really quickly over time.

Sometimes you see clients use the `Keep-Alive:` header but that's legacy from the HTTP/1.0 days and is virtually pointless in this day and age.

If the connection closes after 90 seconds as claimed in this question, that is because the server closes idle connections then. Servers do that. You can't prevent them in any other way than to use the connection again before the server kills it.

## TCP Keepalive

The TCP keepalive options are at an entirely different level. That's basically TCP sending a packet over the connection after N seconds of inactivity, in order to make sure the connection is kept alive (and to detect broken connections).

libcurl does not enable TCP keepalive by default, see [CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE.html).

Comment: Is there any way to **debug** the usage of the TCP-level keepalive? I was trying via `-v` as well as `--trace - ` on https://httpbin.org/delay/3 an was hoping to see **something** in the debug output, but the output looks excatly the same with and without specifying `--keepalive-time 1` (I.e. no indicator of a keepalive probe being sent). Example: `curl --keepalive-time 1 https://httpbin.org/delay/3 -v`

Comment: (drifting away from the original question) TCP keepalive is done by the TCP stack and curl can't show them. I'd recommend using Wireshark to snoop on and analyze the traffic.

Comment: you can use tcpdump to check the keepalives

Comment: If libcurl tries to reuse an HTTP Keep-alive connection and finds that the server has disconnected the connection (such as the 90s timeout in the above example). 

At this point, will libcurl report an error to the caller or will it quietly try to create a new HTTP connection on the current handle and retry the request?

Comment: then libcurl will create a new connection and use that